# get name of object following 2 time a relationship (2x has_many)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, relationship, has-many-through

I have an author, who writes products, which are placed in groups.
What I want to do is to list the groups that an author is involved into.

So, I have first to follow the link from author to products, which works with :

```
@author = Author.find(params[:id])
@products = @author.products
```

which gives lot of products :-) Then I have to find (all) the groups that are linked to all of the products (because a group can contain a lot of products, I have already a has_many link with group_id column in the product table)

But when I try to write something as

```
@groups = @author.products.groups
```

I get the error : undefined method `groups' for # Class:0x000000032a2198

Why ?

Here is the model, where only the "through" clauses seem not to work ?

```
class Author < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :products
  has_many :groups, :through => :products
end
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :group
  has_and_belongs_to_many :authors
end
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :authors, :through => :products
end
```

Thanks !

Edit : I found an ugly way to do what I want. **But is there no better RoR way ??**

```
def show
@author = Author.find(params[:id])
    @products = @author.products
    @groups = []
    @products.each do |product|
        group = Group.find(product.group_id)
        unless @groups.include?(group)
            @groups << group
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there's no way to do it in a Rails way. First, here's how to make what you have more "Railsy":

```
def show
  @author = Author.find(params[:id])
  @products = @author.products
  @groups = []
  @products.each do |product|
    unless @groups.include?(product.group)
      @groups << group
    end
  end
end
```

But a shorter way would be:

```
@products.map(&:group).uniq
```

Quick explanation of what it's doing.  First it's using the symbol to proc shorthand that was introduced in Rails 1.1 (http://blog.hasmanythrough.com/2006/3/7/symbol-to-proc-shorthand).  That builds an array of groups.  Then b/c, in your question, you are checking for uniqueness (using include?) I call [.uniq](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000276) which weeds out any duplicates.

Comment: I like your last sentence... but I only understand the word "uniq", which indicates you're building a big table which becomes reduced after... i'm going to check the doc on this. Thx for helping !

Comment: Sorry, but your simplification doesn't work on my side.

NameError in AuthorsController#show

undefined local variable or method `group' for # AuthorsController:0x0000000282c538 

It seems that "group" is unknown from "product", but I have a has_many/belongs_to link ... ?

Comment: Open up rails console (Rails 3: rails c; Rails 2: script/console) and type "Product.first.group".  Assuming Product.first isn't nil, if that returns an error, there's deeper problems going on.  Although, what you have in your original question looks correct (with regards to the Product/Group relationship).

Answer (score 0):

I also found another way to do this :

```
@user = User.find(params[:id])
@groupcollect = []
@user.products.each { |e| @groupcollect << e.group_id}   # collect group_id for all products
@mygroups = Group.find(@groupcollect.uniq)        # gets the groups for all group_id, unique
```

:-)